# Send data over serial port using QSerialPort

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I want to communicate with a hardware device using the serial port. According to the documentation a message looks like this: 
[image]

I want to use `QSerialPort` for the communication. Here's what I'm trying:

```
QByteArray bytes;
bytes.append(( char) 0x6E);
bytes.append(( char) 0x00);
bytes.append(( char) 0x00);
bytes.append(( char) 0x0B);
bytes.append(( char) 0x00);
bytes.append(( char) 0x00);
bytes.append(( char) 0x2F);
bytes.append(( char) 0x4A);
bytes.append(( char) 0x00);
bytes.append(( char) 0x00);
bytes.append(( char) 0x00);

int transmitted = qSerialPort->write(bytes); //returns no error, transmitted = 11
```

`QSerialPort` is configures like this:

```
qSerialPort = new QSerialPort(path);
qSerialPort->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
qSerialPort->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
qSerialPort->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
qSerialPort->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
qSerialPort->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
qSerialPort->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
```

I don't get a correct response from the HW device. Is there anything I have overlooked for sending hex values to a serial port using `QSerialPort`? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. You overlooked posting a complete test case. Namely, there's nothing in your question that tells us that you correctly read the data from the device.

Comment: Side note: You can write the packet as a string: `const char data[] = "\x6E\x00\x00...\x00"; transmitted = qSerialPort->write(data, sizeof(data)-1); `

Comment: The contents of your packet are likely wrong. You put "\x00" as the data section, yet you didn't compute the proper CRC for that section. Refer to the protocol's documentation for which CRC you're supposed to use, and then compute the CRC prior to sending the packet.

Answer (score 0):

You should open port before "set" operations. For example, in Qt documantation for [baudRate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html#baudRate-prop):

> Note: If the setting is set before opening the port, the actual serial
>   port setting is done automatically in the QSerialPort::open() method
>   right after that the opening of the port succeeds.

Code example:

```
QList<QSerialPortInfo> portsInfo = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();
foreach(const QSerialPortInfo& portInfo, portsInfo){
    if (portInfo.portName().trimmed().toUpper() != /*your port name*/)
        continue;
    _port = new QSerialPort(portInfo, this);
    if (!_port->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)){
        QSerialPort::SerialPortError error = _port->error();
        delete _port;
        _port = nullptr;
    }
    if (!_port->setBaudRate(/*your baudRate*/, /*your direction)*/){
        QSerialPort::SerialPortError error = _port->error();
        _port->close();
        delete _port;
        _port = nullptr;
        return;
    }
    if (!_port->setParity(/*your parity*/)){
        QSerialPort::SerialPortError error = _port->error();
        _port->close();
        delete _port;
        _port = nullptr;
        return;
    }
    if (!_port->setDataBits(/*your dataBits*/)){
        QSerialPort::SerialPortError error = _port->error();
        _port->close();
        delete _port;
        _port = nullptr;
        return;
    }
    if (!_port->setStopBits(/*your stopBits */)){
        QSerialPort::SerialPortError error = _port->error();
        _port->close();
        delete _port;
        _port = nullptr;
        return;
    }
    if (!_port->setFlowControl(/* your flowControl*/)){
        QSerialPort::SerialPortError error = _port->error();
        _port->close();
        delete _port;
        _port = nullptr;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, opening the port first had no effect.

Comment: Did you try to change your HW device? Or maybe use rs232 senders for test device. Something like this: https://sourceforge.net/projects/rs232msgsender/